# Inseting OLEDB connection to tab and prior colums shifting to right

Tags: excel, oledb

I am having a rookie issue but cant seem to figure it out.

I have an OLEDB connection and I am telling it to input data in say cell B1.

But B1 has prior month data and another tab links to it and picking up the data. When I put my OLEDB table to start in B1, the old cells are moved to say column X1. So OLEDB connection data/Table stars in B1 and prior data moved to X1.

I want it to over write the B1 so I an preserve the links pointing to the data tab and not relink everything

I am using the data --> Import from Ohter sources-->Data connection wizard

No VBA codes, just simple connection using the wizard

Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a work around.

Say you want to replace the prior data and not have Excel insert new tabs and shift everything right.

for example your original tab is "sales" and the data starts in B1 cell.

You create a new sheet , sheet 1. Link the table to sheet 1 using OLEDB

Then copy the table and paste it over the old table in sales 1. Just make sure in properties check the button , overwrite exisiting data.

Delete sheet1 and done.